# UIDatePicker Timer with specific hours (Swift)

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, swift2

i have a `UIDatePicker` which shows  hours and minutes  ,  its working fine but i want to show only hours from 6 to 11 in my picker ,  i tried to set the minimum and maximum date with a difference of 5 hours between 2 same dates  but it didn't seems to work any idea what should i do , how can i achieve this ? or does is it even possible or not do i have to create my own custom Time picker by using `UIPickerView` ? please let me know

this is how i set the minimum and maximum dates for my `UIDatePicker` :

```
dateCompForPicker.year = 2015
    dateCompForPicker.day = 10
    dateCompForPicker.month = 10
    dateCompForPicker.hour = 07 // minimum hour 07
    dateCompForPicker.minute = 00


    dateCompForPicker2.year = 2015
    dateCompForPicker2.day = 10
    dateCompForPicker2.month = 10
    dateCompForPicker2.hour = 11   // maximum hour 11
    dateCompForPicker2.minute = 00


    datePicker.minimumDate = dateCompForPicker.date
    datePicker.maximumDate = dateCompForPicker2.date
```

Comment: So are you saying you want a picker with two columns - one for hour and one for minutes. And the hour column should only have the numbers 6 through 11?

Comment: yes @rmaddy i want exactly what you said

Comment: Then use a simple `UIPickerView`. You aren't dealing with dates here.

Comment: okay but how am going to retrieve the selected row as NSdate ? any clue please ?

Comment: You don't have a date. You have an hour and a minute.

Comment: yeah but i have to convert it to NSDate because this picker is for setting the fireDate of a UILocalnotification which haves a time interval so the dates does not matter here i just have to provide the hours and minutes

Comment: i was able to do it while using the UIDatepicker

Comment: Once you have the hours and minutes, you can create an `NSDate` from those using `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111936/discussion-between-remy-boys-and-rmaddy).